# Offset height using Prototype

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

I get different values from Prototype's `cumulativeOffset` function in Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 3.5 within a complex layout with several elements having paddings and margins.

This seems to be a known bug: [Discussion](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/188-element-cumulativeoffset-and-positionedoffset-need-to-check-for-offsettop-and-offsetleft-bugs)

Does anybody know a prototype based or prototype compatible method of reliably determining the offset height of a statically positioned element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a diagram from [Kangax's cheat sheet](http://thinkweb2.com/projects/prototype/prototype-1602-cheat-sheet/), who is one of the members of the Prototype DEV team.

[alt text http://preview.moveable.com/JM/dev/prototype_cheatsheet_1.6.0.png](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/dev/prototype_cheatsheet_1.6.0.png)

You could add the viewport offset and the scroll offsets, but I'm not sure of this will contain the same issue.

Most of the time I use this [Quirksmode script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) for finding element positions:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    //find coordinates of a DIV
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft = obj.offsetLeft
        curtop = obj.offsetTop
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft
            curtop += obj.offsetTop
        }
    }
    return [curleft, curtop];
}
```

Comment: The quirksmode script works fine and I think I will be using that. Thanks!

Comment: For any who may not know, Quirksmode is the blog of the man behind jQuery, so it's a fair bet that using jQuery directly when it's an option will yield similar results (probably uses the same code for its measuring).

Comment: the quirksmode script worked fine across FF/IE/Chrome for me until i added a border-top to <body>. then i got totally different (!) values in FF/IE/Chrome :(